# VB6 How to decode Chinese Characters with the HTML code

Tags: vba, vb6

I need to decode the following text (just partial of it) and it consists of Chinese traditional characters. I have tried some decoding code but it doesn't work. After decoded, it turned out to be ????

PART OF THE Encoded Text:

```
%3Ctable%20width%3D%22100%25%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctr%3E%3Ctd%3E%3Cp%20style%3D%22color%3A%23000000%3Bfont-size%3A20pt%3Btext-align%3Acenter%3Bfont-weight%3Abold%22%3E%0D%0A%09Genie%E7%93%B6%E4%B8%AD%E7%B2%BE%E9%9D%88%2010%25%E6%9D%8F%E4%BB%81%E9%85%B8%E4%BA%AE%E9%87%87%E7%85%A5%E8%86%9A%E7%B2%BE%E8%8F%AF%E6%B6%B2%20%E8%B2%B7%E4%B8%80%E9%80%81%E4%B8%80%0D%0A%3C%2Fp%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Ftd%3E%3C%2Ftr%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctr%3E%3Ctd%3E%3Cp%20style%3D%22color%3A%23000000%3Bfont-size%3A12pt%3Btext-align%3Acenter%22%3E%0D%0A%09%20%0D%0A%3C%2Fp%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Ftd%3E%3C%2Ftr%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctr%3E%3Ctd%3E%3Cdiv%20align%3D%22center%22%3E%3Cimg%20src%3D%22https%3A%2F%2Fs.yimg.com%2Fwb%2Fimages%2F3C8EF489980779600D2E2A95C5BB2E0C15859F8B%22%20%2F%3E%3C%2Fdiv%3E%3C%2Ftd%3E%3C%2Ftr%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Ftable%3E%3Ctable%20width%3D%22100%25%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctr%3E%3Ctd%3E%3Cp%20style%3D%22color%3A%23000000%3Bfont-size%3A12pt%3Btext-align%3Aleft%3Bfont-weight%3A100%22%3E%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%3C%2Fp%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Ftd
```

After DECODED: You can see the Chinese characters being decoded as `????`

```html
<div align=center><TABLE width="100
<TBODY>
<TR>
<TD>
<P style="FONT-SIZE: 20pt; FONT-WEIGHT: bold; COLOR: #000000; TEXT-ALIGN: center">
Genie???? 10???????? ???? </P>
</TD>
```

Please help how to decode it properly.

```vb
Private Const CP_UTF8 As Long = 65001 ' UTF-8 Code Page

'Sys call to convert multiple byte chars to a char
Private Declare Function MultiByteToWideChar Lib "kernel32" ( _
    ByVal CodePage As Long, _
    ByVal dwFlags As Long, _
    ByVal lpMultiByteStr As Long, _
    ByVal cchMultiByte As Long, _
    ByVal lpWideCharStr As Long, _
    ByVal cchWideChar As Long) As Long

Private Function URL8Decode(ByVal URLEncoded As String) As String
On Error GoTo executeError
    Dim ANSI() As Byte
    Dim UTF8() As Byte
    Dim I As Long
    Dim B As Long

    URLEncoded = Replace$(URLEncoded, "+", " ") 'Optional, plus-encoding isn't always used.
    ANSI = StrConv(URLEncoded, vbFromUnicode)
    ReDim UTF8(UBound(ANSI)) 'Estimate.
    For I = 0 To UBound(ANSI)
        If ANSI(I) = &H25 Then
            UTF8(B) = FromHex(ANSI(I + 1)) * &H10 + FromHex(ANSI(I + 2)) 'Val("&H" & Mid$(URLEncoded, I + 2, 2))
            I = I + 2
        Else
            UTF8(B) = ANSI(I)
        End If
        B = B + 1
    Next
    URL8Decode = FromUTF8(UTF8, B)
    Exit Function
executeError:
    LogProcess "ProductDetailFrm URL8Decode - [Err=" & Err.description & "]"
    Resume 'HANG

End Function

Private Function FromHex(ByVal Char As Byte) As Byte
On Error GoTo executeError
    If Char <= &H39 Then
        FromHex = Char - &H30
    Else
        FromHex = Char - &H41 + &HA
    End If
     Exit Function
executeError:
    LogProcess "ProductDetailFrm FromHex - [Err=" & Err.description & "]"
End Function
```

Comment: What have you tired? Is this VB or VBA?

Comment: Hi Gareth, I've shared the code above.

Comment: While the code might be improved a little it probably works just fine.  I'd bet you are trying to display the result in an ANSI control though, and thus your `???` issue.

Answer (score 0):

See if this code help you. I am using the JavaScript capabilities to decode.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

    Const sEncoded As String = "%3Ctable%20width%3D%22100%25%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctr%3E%3Ctd%3E%3Cp%20style%3D%22color%3A%23000000%3Bfont-size%3A20pt%3Btext-align%3Acenter%3Bfont-" & _
                                "weight%3Abold%22%3E%0D%0A%09Genie%E7%93%B6%E4%B8%AD%E7%B2%BE%E9%9D%88%2010%25%E6%9D%8F%E4%BB%81%E9%85%B8%E4%BA%AE%E9%87%87%E7%85%A5%E8%86%9A%E7%B2%BE%E8%8F%AF%E6%B6%B2%20%E8%B2%B7%E4%B8%80%E9%80%81%E4%B8%80%0D%0A%3C%2Fp%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Ftd" & _
                                "%3E%3C%2Ftr%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctr%3E%3Ctd%3E%3Cp%20style%3D%22color%3A%23000000%3Bfont-size%3A12pt%3Btext-align%3Acenter%22%3E%0D%0A%09%20%0D%0A%3C%2" & _
                                "Fp%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Ftd%3E%3C%2Ftr%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctr%3E%3Ctd%3E%3Cdiv%20align%3D%22center%22%3E%3Cimg%20src%3D%22https%3A%2F%2Fs.yimg.com%2Fwb%2Fimages%" & _
                                "2F3C8EF489980779600D2E2A95C5BB2E0C15859F8B%22%20%2F%3E%3C%2Fdiv%3E%3C%2Ftd%3E%3C%2Ftr%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Ftable%3E%3Ctable%20width%3D%22100%25%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%" & _
                                "20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctr%3E%3Ctd%3E%3Cp%20style%3D%22color%3A%23000000%3Bfont-size%3A12pt%3Btext-align%3Aleft%3Bfont-weight%3A100%22%3E%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%3C%2Fp%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Ftd"


    ' I am writing the values to Range("A1")
    Cells(1, 1).Value = DecodeHTML(sEncoded)

End Sub

'Decodes the string using a javasript object.
Function DecodeHTML(ByVal strCharacters As String) As String

    Dim oScrip As Object
    Dim ret As String

    Set oScrip = CreateObject("MSScriptControl.ScriptControl")

    With oScrip
        .Language = "JScript"
        .AddCode "function decode(x) {return decodeURIComponent(x);}"
        ret = .Run("decode", strCharacters)
    End With

    'Return the value
    DecodeHTML = ret

End Function
```

Just run the Test() procedure.

Thanks I hope this helps :)

Comment: On Windows 8+ one would use [`UrlUnescape`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773791%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with `URL_UNESCAPE_AS_UTF8` flag set, but on earlier Windows this scripting approach might be sensible, given that `UrlUnescape` without the flag returns partially invalid data.

Comment: Hi Fredlo, thanks! I'll try it out .... on my VB 6.... and will let you know whether does it work.

Comment: Hi Fredlo, it hit error of The "URI to be decoded is not a valid encoding"

Comment: This is a common error found when the characters tried to decode are not real. It happened to me when trying to test the code in a section of a string. Try it with real ("encoded") data and you should not have a problem.

Comment: Hi Fredlo, thanks a lot !!! Is there any function that we can use it to test non-encoded and encoded string? Because sometime the string is encoded and sometime it doesn't that's where it hit the error.

Comment: what website are you getting this information from?